# A question on deformation retracts of cochain complexes

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $(A,d)$ be a cochain complex. A deformation retract of $(A, d)$ is a cochain complex $(H, d_H)$ together with morphisms $i: H \to A$ (of degree $0$), $p: A \to H$ (of degree $0$) and $h: A \to A$ (of degree $-1$) such that
$$
pi = \textrm{id},\quad dh + hd = ip - \textrm{id}.
$$

Suppose we are given two deformation retracts $(H,i,p,h)$ and $(H,i,p,h')$ of $(A,d)$ (note that they only differ on $h$). Is it true that $h - h'$ is a boundary (in $\textrm{End}(A)$), i.e. there exists some morphism $f: A \to A$ of degree $-2$ such that $h - h' = df - fd$?

From my experience I believe this has to be true, but I can't find a way to prove it...

*Side question:* What if we have two deformation retracts $(H, i, p, h)$ and $(H, i', p', h')$? Is it still true that $h - h'$ is a boundary?

*Side question 2:* Finally, what happens if we have two deformation retracts $(H, i, p, h)$ and $(H', i', p', h')$? Is it still true that $h-h'$ is a boundary?

Comment: I will think tomorrow a little on it, but my feeling is, the first step should be true, as h essentially only serves as a homotopy between the two chain complexes (assuming id is the identity), the second I think is wrong. This is essentially a baby version of Kadaishvili if you want to check it out

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up! Maybe it can be shown using fillers in the quasi-category of cochain complexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. Actually $h-h^{\prime}$ only needs to be a cycle, i.e. $d(h-h^{\prime})+(h-h^{\prime})d=0$. This is because $dh+hd=ip-id$ is the only condition that $h$ and $h^{\prime}$ need to satisfy.

For example consider the complex $(C^{\bullet},d)=k^2\to k^2$ concentrated in degree $0$ and $1$ with differential $d=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Then it is clear that the cohomology $H^0(C^{\bullet},d)=k$ and $H^1(C^{\bullet},d)=k$. Moreover $p$ is the projection onto the second component in both degree $0$ and $1$ and $i$ is the natural embedding. We then obtain $ip=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

We can choose for example $h=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $h^{\prime}=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, both of which are homotopy operators for $ip-1$. However $h$ and $h^{\prime}$ are not differed by a boundary because there is no non-zero degree $-2$ term in $End(C^{\bullet})$.

Actually whenever $H^{−1}(End(C^{\bullet}),d)\neq 0$, $h$
and $h^{\prime}$
may be differed by merely a cycle instead of a boundary.

Comment: Could you please give a counterexample then?

Comment: Yes, consider the complex $k^2\to k^2$ which focuses on degree $0$ and $1$ with differential $d=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $ip=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$. It is clear that $h=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $h^{\prime}=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ are both homotopy operators for $ip-1$, but $h$ and $h^{\prime}$ are not differed by a boundary because there is no non-zero degree $-2$ term in $End(C^{\bullet})$. Actually whenever $H^{-1}(End(C^{\bullet}),d)\neq 0$, $h$ and  $h^{\prime}$  may be differed by merely a cycle instead of a boundary.

Comment: Neat, thank you so much!!! If you write it with details in your previous answer I'll give you the tick :)